# Using stored procedures to retrieve data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have written the following C# code to get the data from my database:

```
public static DataTable GetDetails(string startDate, string endDate, char isSpam, string Name)
{
    string getDetilasQuery = @"sp_getDetails";

    SqlParameter[] objSqlParameter = {  new SqlParameter("@isDeleted",'n'),
                                        new SqlParameter("@startDate",startDate),
                                        new SqlParameter("@endDate",endDate),
                                        new SqlParameter("@isSpam",isSpam),
                                        new SqlParameter("@Name",Name)
                                     };

    return DL.decryptDataSet(SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(strConnectionString, CommandType.Text, getDetilasQuery, objSqlParameter)).Tables[0];
}
```

And my stored procedure is as follows :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getDetails]
    (@isDeleted CHAR(1),
     @startDate DATETIME,
     @endDate DATETIME,
     @isSpam CHAR(1),
     @Name VARCHAR(MAX)) 
 As
 BEGIN 
     SELECT 
         col1, col2.... 
     FROM
         tbl_getData 
     WHERE
         added BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate 
         AND isDeleted = @isDeleted
END
```

but whenever I try to retrieve the data using following code and stored procedure, I get an error

> Stored procedure expects parameter @isDeleted which is not supplied!

However I have passed a parameter `@isDeleted` using `SqlParameter[]` as seen in the code.

Can anyone tell me whether I am missing something, or any changes in code or stored procedure?

Comment: Change `CommandType.Text` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

Comment: I have to say this is one of the most annoying error messages. I mean, it seems clear from the text that ado.net "know" this is a stored procedure, and the problem is not that lack of a parameter but the wrong `commandType`. It should be a different error message.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for figuring out my mistake! :-)

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @ZoharPeled you are right, I was unable to figure out the problem based on the error.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: No -- ADO.NET has no idea what's in your command text. It's SQL Server which process the "query" `sp_getDetails`, interprets this as `EXEC sp_getDetails` without the `EXEC`, and then gives the error that you're missing parameters. You'd get the same error in Management Studio. (Technically, of course, ADO.NET could have special handling for when SQL Server returns precisely this error, but it would be hard to get this right in all cases, just for the improved user experience.) This is exactly why `CommandType.StoredProcedure` exists in the first place.

Comment: Very annoying error message, I think I have seen three posts on SO with this same problem/solution this week alone

Comment: If you change the first param to some other param, does it clash with the new variable?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Well, that explains it, thanks!. (though SQL Server itself could just issue a "missing exec keyword" or something like that)

Comment: @ZoharPeled: I suspect that if we go all the way back, we'll find the ability to execute stored procedures without specifying `EXEC` was already there when they were introduced way back when in the original Sybase product (almost 30 years ago). In any case, it's way too late now to change this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Jeroen Changing CommandType.Text to CommandType.StoredProcedure does the job.